# Azure ML Studio cannot load a installed package in R

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

[image]

I am trying to install a package in azure ML studio using the command below.

```
install.packages("src/DMwR.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
library(DMwR, lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE)
```

DMwR.zip was upload as a dataset in azure. The error I get is below.

```
Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:
---------- Start of error message from R ----------
zip file 'src/DMwR.zip' not found
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The error says that the package *wasn't* installed because it wasn't found. How did you upload this zip file?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos updated with screen shot.

Comment: That's a screenshot of *datasets*, not packages. It doesn't show any `src` folder either. Just check what is the correct path for these files and use it, instead of the relative path `src/DMwR.zip`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos according to the blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjguin/2014/09/24/how-to-upload-an-r-package-to-azure-machine-learning/. This should be copied to the dataset folder.

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a folder on your local drive with any name.
2. Put the package you want (DMwR.zip) into that folder.
3. Zip the entire folder
4. Upload it using New->Dataset->From local file
5. Now you can refer the package inside your R code using 'src/DMwR.zip' path.